# web3.admin.addpeers return BigNumber Error

Tags: web3js, cpp-ethereum, peers

When I using ethconsole to deal with a private chain. I hope it can connects to another node which I get the node information.
But the command "web3.admin.addPeer("enode://...@192.168.1.29:30304",function () { console.log(arguments) })" return an error.
That is "BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: enode://...@192.168.1.29:30304 ".
What happened here? How to connect to another node by using ethconsole in cpp-ethereum client?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#admin_addpeer) you are able to use the following command in the console `admin.addPeer(url)`

This is the example given by the docs:
`admin.addPeer("enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c@52.16.188.185:30303")`

Maybe you could try the same without the `web3.`

Comment: Thank you for replay. But what I'm using is ethconsole which just have node.js code. If I just enter "web3.admin.addPeer("enode://...@192.168.1.29:30304")"  that will return an error like "Error: You tried to send "miner_addPeer" synchronously. Synchronous requests are not supported by the IPC provider". And if I try that without the "web3." that just cannot use.

Comment: And I believe the command of doc in example is for go-ethereum, and I have use cpp-ethereum. I have not see any guild in the website.